# PyCharm updated and now every script gets executed in Python Console

Tags: python, pycharm, ubuntu-18.04

This morning when I got into the office, PyCharm said I need to update my IDE, so I updated it to the latest "professional" PyCharm edition.  However, whenever I run my code, it now goes to Python Console pane instead of a Run pane appearing.  At first, interactive python was completely broken, but after I redownloaded IPython, I got the interactive portion back, but my run is still missing.  Please refer to the below pictures.

As you can see, in the new PyCharm, the title of the runs are called "Python Console (1), Python Console (2), etc with no names, and it is ran in Python console.
In the old PyCharm, the file had its respective name and was in the "4. Run" category on the bottom left of PyCharm, and not in the Console section.

[New PyCharm after IDE Update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSuNw.png)

[Old PyCharm with Run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGpT6.png)

Additional Info:  I am using Python 3.6, PyCharm Professional Edition, Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Sounds like PyCharm lost the project settings, or you may have told it to clear its settings after the update. Just go into Settings and set the Project location and "Add Content Root"

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I added the content root to my current directory, but it is still showing the same thing :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to disable **Run with Python console** option in the Run Configuration:

[image]

Comment: Hello Pavel, thanks for the reply.  This solved the Console issue.  I think the main issue arrived from me updating my PyCharm.  I usually right click my code and click 'run in console", because by doing so, I won't get the "Process finished with exit code 1".  This way, I can see my results after my runs.  However, with the new PyCharm update, they changed how this works unfortunately.  I downgraded my PyCharm and now it is working as before as well.